# Adding input box dynamically for inline edit

Tags: jquery

Yesterday I have posted one code for adding text box in inline edit,I got the following correct answer.
https://jsfiddle.net/wjb0an9m/4/

Now the same thing I am trying with ajax call and getting data's from db.But text box is appending multiple times.that is `I have one table with 5 rows,When I click edit button in first row text box is appended 5 times similarly when I click edit in second row,Text box is appended 4 times and so on.`
I don't know what I did wrong.
Please anyone let me know what I did wrong

```
function empRoles() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/Admin/getRolesList",
        data:'{}',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response)
            var roleList = response;
            $('#content').html('');
            for (var i = 0; i < roleList.length; i++) {
                var table = '<tr  id="' + roleList[i].Id + '"><td>' + (i + 1) + '</td><td class="roleName" id="name' + i + '"><p>' + roleList[i].name + '</p></td><td><button  class="btn edit btn-info" id="edit' + i + '"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Edit</button><button  class="btn update btn-success" id="update' + i + '"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>Update</button><button class="btn dlt btn-danger" onclick="deleteRow(this)" data-dismiss="modal" ><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>Delete</button></td><tr>';
                $('#content').append(table);
                editUpdate();
            }
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            noData()
        }
    });
}
function noData() {
    $('.noData').show();
}
function editUpdate() {
    $('.update').hide();
    $('.edit').click(function () {debugger

        var editId = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).parents('tr').find('td.roleName').append('<input>');
        $(this).parents('tr').find('td.roleName > p').hide();
        $(this).parents('tr').find('td.roleName>input').val($(this).parents('tr').find('td.rolename > p').text());
        $("#" + editId).hide();
        var number = editId.replace("edit", "");
        $("#update" + number).show();

        var currentTD = $(this).parents('tr').find(':nth-child(2)');
       //$.each(currentTD, function () {
       //   $(this).prop('contenteditable', true)            
       // });
    });

    $('.update').click(function () {

        var updateId = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#" + updateId).hide();
        var number = updateId.replace("update", "");
        $("#edit" + number).show();

        var currentTD = $(this).parents('tr').find(':nth-child(2)');
        if ($(currentTD).has('input')) {
            $(currentTD).find('p').text($(currentTD).find('input').val());
            $(currentTD).find('input').hide();
            $(currentTD).find('p').show();
        }
        $.each(currentTD, function () {
            $(this).prop('contenteditable', false)
        });

        var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
        var name = $(this).parents('tr').find(':nth-child(2)').html();
        var Roles = { name: name, role_id: id };
        var ajxObj = { oRoles: Roles };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/Admin/RoleUpdate",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(ajxObj),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                $(".roleCreated").html("Role Updated successfully!");
                $('.roleCreated').show();
                setTimeout(function () {
                     $('.roleCreated').hide();
                 }, 1500);
                empRoles()
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
    });

}
```

I din't add completed code because its connected with db and controllers .That is why I add only `edit` and `update` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with your implementation is that your are bind event handler in the `editUpdate`  function, so whenever the function is executed a new event handlers is attached with `$('.edit')` and `$('.update')` elements.

You should use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) method with [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) approach, when generating elements dynamically.

*General Syntax*

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

*Relevant code*

```
function editUpdate() {
    $('.update').hide();
}

$('#content').on('click', '.edit', function () {
    //Your existing code
});

$('#content').on('click', '.update', function () {
    //Your existing code
});
```

---

Another approach would be the usage of [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

```
function editUpdate() {
    $('.update').hide();
    $('.edit').off('click').on('click', function () {
        //Your existing code
    });

    $('.update').off('click').on('click', function () {
        //Your existing code
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried this,text box is appending correctly but data is hiding in a related `td`

Comment: When I use `.on()` method my code should be in inside of `document.ready()` right?.But I am using `controllers` and `methods` from asp.net how I can I call it from `document.ready()`? that is why I have used separate function

Comment: @krish, You can bind event handler using `$(document).on('click', '.edit', function () {
    //Your existing code
});` and just put them in document-ready and I have also provided alternate option

Comment: Ohh ok .Then why  data is hiding :(

Comment: @krish, You have to investigate it as I have not suggested any modification to that approach

Comment: Is there any other way to use `event delegation` method inside of `onclick()`.Don't mistake me am new to this that is why asking.